# Password Reset Not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, email

I am new to laravel. I want to implement the login and registeration using laravel auth. I have implemented the login and registration flow successfully but I am not able to implement reset password.
I am facing the following issue:
1. After submitting the username/email some processing happens but I am not able to send the password reset link using the email. It always got a screen which says we have emailed your password reset link but nothing is happening. The entries are being made in the password_resets table.
Any help will be much appreciated.

I am using the gmail to send the password reset emails. After doing a lot of debugging everything looks fine apart from ResetPassword.php file which is executed till

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
   // echo "<pre>".print_r($notifiable,1)."</pre>";exit("<br/>sdds");
    return ['mail'];
}
```

There is a function in this file which is created to send the emails but this function is not going called. The function is given below :

```
 /**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    echo "<pre>".print_r($notifiable,1)."</pre>";exit();
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', route('password.reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Here are the main file used in this

Authorisation model class RetailUserAuth.php

```
    <?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
   class RetailUserAuth extends Authenticatable
   {
     use Notifiable;
     //protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
protected $table = 'retail_user_auth';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = ['username', 'user_id', 'password','source','user_status'];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

**SendsPasswordResetEmails.php**

```
  <?php

   namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

  trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
  {
    /**
    * Display the form to request a password reset link.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('auth.passwords.email');
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required|email']);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('username')
    );

    //echo "</pre>".print_r($response,1)."</pre>";exit();
    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
{
    return back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return back()->withErrors(
        ['username' => trans($response)]
    );
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker();
}
}
```

**CanResetPassword.php**

```
    <?php

     namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

     use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as 
 ResetPasswordNotification;

  trait CanResetPassword
 {
/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
}
```

**ResetPassword.php**

```
   <?php

   namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;

   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

  class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
/**
 * The password reset token.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $token;

/**
 * Create a notification instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    //echo $token;exit('<br/>fdfdffd');
    $this->token = $token;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array|string
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
   // echo "<pre>".print_r($notifiable,1)."</pre>";exit("<br/>sdds");
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    echo "<pre>".print_r($notifiable,1)."</pre>";exit();
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', route('password.reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to send any email through Laravel, just as a test?

Comment: No I haven't tried this. But I am not able to understand why toMail function is not being executed in ResetPassword.php file?